# Is the 'marveled' expression in Greek used in Mark 6:6, Luke 7:9 and Matthew 8:10 the same one?

Tags: greek, textual-criticism, faith

I've head a preacher making the case for a sermon regarding this, it was very interesting. My limited insight into it seems to confirm it, but can someone help clarify?

Mark 6:6 KJV

> And he **marvelled** because of their unbelief. And he went round about the villages, teaching.

Luke 7:9 KJV

> When Jesus heard these things, he **marvelled** at him, and turned him about, and said unto the people that followed him, I say unto you, I have not found so great faith, no, not in Israel.

Matthew 8:10 KJV

> When Jesus heard it, he **marvelled**, and said to them that followed, Verily I say unto you, I have not found so great faith, no, not in Israel.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: check biblehub greek interlinear then the lexicon meanings, or from blueletterbible, and stepbible org site.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, all three verbs in Matt 8:10, Mark 6:6 & Luke 7:9 are the same Greek verb, namely, θαυμάζω (thaumazó) which occurs 44 times in the NT text.  The various shades of meaning of this verb are given by BDAG as:

1. **to be extraordinarily impressed or disturbed by something**

- (a) intransitive: *wonder, marvel, be astonished* (the context determines whether in a good sense or bad sense), eg, Matt 8:10, 15:31, 22:22, 27:14, Mark 5:20, 15:5, Luke 1:21, 63, 8:25, 11:14, 24:41, John 5:20, 7:21, Acts 4:13, 13:12, 41, Rev 17:7, Gal 1:6, etc
- (b) transitive: *admire, wonder at, respect*, eg, Luke 24:12, John 5:28, Acts 7:31, Luke 7:9, Jude 16, 2 Thess 1:10.

2. ***Wonder, be amazed***, as deponent with aorist and future passive:, eg, Rev 17:8, 13:3.

Note that Mark 6:6 and Matt 8:10 are intransitive cases but Luke 7:9 is a transitive case.  Further, Mark 6:6 is an astonishment in a bad sense (because of unbelief) while Luke 7:9 and matt 8:10 is astonishment in a good sense (because of commendable faith).

Lastly, while the same verb is involved, the grammatical inflexion is slightly different in each case.  All this is summarized in the list below:

- Mark 6:6 - ἐθαύμαζεν = imperative indicative active, 3rd person singular [intransitive; marveled in a bad sense]
- Luke 7:9 - ἐθαύμασεν = aorist indicative active, 3rd person singular [transitive; marveled in a good sense]
- Matt 8:10 - ἐθαύμασεν = aorist indicative active, 3rd person singular intransitive; marveled in a good sense]

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you mean then yes these verses use the same word in Greek.

[Mark 6:6 KJV interlinear](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/mark/6-6.htm)

[Luke 7:9 KJV interlinear](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/luke/7-9.htm)

[Mathew 8:10 KJV interlinear](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/matthew/8-10.htm)

[Here](https://biblehub.com/greek/2296.htm) are also other passages that use the same root word.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.